# expected ',' javascript firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have this problem in javascript code

expected ',' in line   `like: like + 1;`

expected ',' in line  `dislike: dislike + 1;`

**html code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button-container like-container">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"> Like</i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container dislike-container">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"> Dislike</i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript code**

```
var likeDislike = new Firebase("https://like-unlike.firebaseio.com/");

var like;
var dislike;

likeDislike.on("value", function(likeDislikeData) {
    var data = likeDislikeData.val();
    like = data.like;
    dislike = data.dislike;
});

$('.like-container').on('click', function() {
    likeDislike.update({
        like: like + 1;
    });
    console.log("Number of likes:" + like);
});

$('.dislike-container a').on('click', function() {
    likeDislike.update({
        dislike: dislike + 1;
    });
    console.log("Number of dislikes: " + dislike);
});
```

Comment: The `update` function takes an `object`, like `{property: value, property2: value2}`. However, yours has a semi-colon in it. If your object only has one key/value pair, it would simply look like `{property: value}`, no semicolon. Assuming that you've gotten your answer, I'm going to vote to close as **Off-topic: simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `;` within an object, you have to separate object properties with commas `,`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `;` inside of a json and you can't.

```
likeDislike.update({
    dislike: dislike + 1; //Error
});
```

Replace this line by:

```
likeDislike.update({
    dislike : dislike + 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define an object, you should separate the properties by comma `,` not `;`. i.e., `dislike: dislike + 1;` should be `dislike: dislike + 1,`.

See the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

In javascript, `;` means end of the statement.